# How does the rewriting of the following two equations work?

Tags: calculus, queueing-theory

I am failing to understand the proof of coming to the steady-state formula in queueing theory. This is probably due to the fact that I may have forgotten (and cannot find it back) some of the algebra from my school days. The step I am missing is the transition from the first to the second statement below:

$$(\lambda + \mu)\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P_0 = \lambda P_0 + \mu P2$$

$$\frac{\lambda^2}{\mu}P0 + \lambda P_0 = \lambda P_0 + \mu P2$$

My main question is how does $$(\lambda + \mu)\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P_0$$ become
$$\frac{\lambda^2}{\mu}P_0 + \lambda P_0$$
and what did happen to: $$\mu$$

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the distributive law: If $a,b,c$ are terms, we have $(a+b)c=ac+bc$. In this case,

$$(\lambda+\mu)\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P_0 = \lambda\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P_0 + \mu\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P_0= \frac{\lambda \cdot \lambda}{\mu}P_0 + \frac{\mu \cdot \lambda}{\mu}P_0 = \frac{\lambda^2}{\mu}P_0 + \lambda P_0.$$

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: I recall that, but then you would expect that somewhere you get a value along the lines this would result in: $$\frac{\lambda^2}{\mu}P_0 + \lambda P_0 + \mu P_0$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. Could you expand on your question a little bit?

Comment: @Jochem It might help to note that $\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P_0$ is one term and plays the role of $c$ in the distributive law.

Comment: This part I understand: $$(\lambda+\mu)\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P_0 = \lambda\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P_0 + \mu\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P_0$$

But when you add them up you get:

$$\frac{\lambda * \lambda}{\mu}P_0 + \frac{\mu * \lambda}{\mu}P_0$$

Is it here that multiplying of the `$$\mu$$` in the second part results in `$$P_0$$`?

Comment: @Jochem That is correct. The first term you wrote at the bottom becomes $\frac{\lambda^2}{\mu}P_0$, and the second is $\lambda P_0$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Jochem Yes. In general, we have $\frac{ab}{b}=a$ for any terms $a$ and $b$ ($b\neq 0$).

Answer (score 1):

This is rather simple actually, all you need to do is expand (distribute the elements).

Expanding this:
$$
(\lambda + \mu)\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P0
$$

We have this:
$$
\frac{\lambda^2}{\mu}P0+\frac{\mu\lambda}{\mu}P0
$$

And the final result after simplification is :
$$
\frac{\lambda^2}{\mu}P0 + \lambda P0
$$

To answer your question about what happened to **$\mu$**. When you simplify: **$\frac{\mu\lambda}{\mu}$** it becomes **$1\lambda$**, which is the same as just **$\lambda$**.

Comment: Thank you. Just went through the same line of thought with @Potato.